# Android ExpandableListView in AlertDialog child view disappearing

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-alertdialog

So I have an ExpandableListView embedded inside and AlertDialog. Everything works fine in that the listview shows up. But for some reason after I click on a group to expand, the AlertDialog will increase its size to make room for the listview children and the children will show, but as soon as the "expanding" animation is finished the child view dissapears. I managed to capture a screenshot of what it looks like.

This is what it SHOULD look like, but this only appears for the duration of the animation after the user clicks a group. (I'd post the actual picture but I don't have enough reputation)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mwrK.png

As soon as the animation finishes, the resulting screen will look like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BULOZ.png

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something wrong with my code. Here is the code I'm using for my AlertDialog

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
    alertDialog.setTitle("Query");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Enter your query");

    ExpandableListView input = createExpandableListView(view);
    alertDialog.setView(input);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Enter",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                   //some code
                }
            });
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.create().show();
```

I'm getting the information for the ExpandableListView in a different function because its dynamically built, so that part isn't being shown. Has anyone encountered a problem like this before?

**UPDATE**
So I think the problem is with the AlertDialog box, because the issue only seems to occur immediately after the dialog box resizes, if I make the AlertDialog box the size of the screen so it can't resize, there is no problem. So perhaps it's repainting the screen after it adjusts to make room for the child items. How do I deal with this issue?

Comment: What is 'view'? And for what it is used in the creation of the expandable list view?

Comment: In this instance view is what's being passed to the function. I have a method named addQuery(View view) that's an action listener for a button in a layout, so when the button is pressed this method is called with that view as the parameter, and that's what's being used to create the AlertDialog and ExpandableListView

Comment: `In this instance view is what's being passed to the function.`. Yes that is what I saw and so i wanted to know what this view was. But you did not tell. `being used to create the AlertDialog and ExpandableListView`. That is what i supposed would hapen. But you did not tell in which way you used it and that was the question.